# Hyundai ix35 clicking turning wheel and rattling going over bumps

Tags: noise, hyundai

Hi my name is Kris carter I own ix35 I have couple of issues clicking noise when turning steering wheel and rattling noise when going over bumps. I’ve had front suspension and control arm replaced I’m  stuck between a rock and a hard place can bad cv joints make rattling noise when going over bumpy. The ratting sounds like a clatter it's coming from right drivers side.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The rattle is coming from right drivers side and it sounds like a clatter type of noise only when going over bumps or speed humps very slowly